# Show text in main panel of shiny app after click of a button

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to learn shiny. I would like to display the text in main panel only after clicking Go button. So, when the app loads, it will have no text in the main panel. How do I do it?
Here is the tweaked code from an example:

```
library(shiny)

UI<-fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Reactivity"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("caption", "Caption:", "Data Summary"),

      textInput("TEXT1", "tEXT:", "Data Summary"), 
      submitButton("Go")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption", container = span)),
      h3(textOutput("TEXT1", container = span))
    )
  )
)

Server<-function(input, output) {

  output$caption <- renderText({
    input$caption
  })

  output$TEXT1 <- renderText({
    input$TEXT1
  })
}

shinyApp(UI, Server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Reactivity"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       textInput("caption", "Caption:", "Data Summary"),
       textInput("TEXT1", "tEXT:", "Data Summary"), 
       actionButton("goButton", "Go")
  ),

    mainPanel(
        h3(textOutput("caption", container = span)),
        h3(textOutput("TEXT1", container = span))
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   cap <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
      input$caption
   })

   text <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
      input$TEXT1
   })

   output$caption <- renderText({
      cap()
   })

   output$TEXT1 <- renderText({
      text()
   })

})
```

Comment: It works. Is it possible to put  `output$caption <- renderText({
      cap()
   })

   output$TEXT1 <- renderText({
      text()
   })` in a function.

Comment: Do the following changes in ui.R:
  
    `mainPanel(
    
        verbatimTextOutput("o1")
    
      )`

And do the following changes in server.R:
  
    `shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
        inputs <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
      
               c(input$caption, input$TEXT1)
      
        })
    
        output$o1 <- renderPrint({
      
               cat(inputs()[1], "\n", inputs()[2])
      
           })  
    
      })`